# GUILayout button not registering a click event ... Why"

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Forgive me if I get the formatting wrong. I rarely come here and I can never seemingly get it right.

'This is my code. I am building a custom terrain generator that textures according to your settings. Everything is working fine, but the button below for text2weight does nothing for some reason. All have the same code - the variables and call the same function to texture the terrain according to selected values. For some reason, texture2's weight button does nothing. It used to work fine. I deleted the code, copied and pasted other code which is identical and nothing. I even put a debug. log statement in the if statement for the button. Nothing. I am lost! Makes no sense. Does anybody have a clue? There are many other buttons just like it that work as expected.'

```cs
    try
    {
        text2MaxSlope = (EditorGUILayout.Slider(text2MaxSlope, 0,90, GUILayout.Height(20)));
    }
    catch
    {
    
    }
    
    GUILayout.Space(4); if (GUILayout.Button("Texture"))
    {
        setVariables();
        TT.TT();    
    }

    GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
    GUILayout.Space(6);
    GUILayout.Label("Weight");
    GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
    
    try
    {
        text2Weight = (EditorGUILayout.Slider(text2Weight, 0, 1, GUILayout.Height(20)));
    }
    catch
    {
    
    }
    ////This one doesn't work? Makes no sense. It used to just fine. 
    
    GUILayout.Space(4); 
    if (GUILayout.Button("Texture"))
    {
        setVariables(); 
        TT.TT();
    }
```

Comment: Im not great at the GUI side, but, does it work if you endhorizontal? it opens and doesnt end on the code provided.

Comment: Yes, the end horizontal, is there I just didn't show it here. It's bizarre. All other buttons work fine and this one used to. This is the only one in a long list that for some reason doesn't register the click event. I put a Debug.Log("Test"); in the buttons code before the function calls and nothing.

Comment: I managed to fix it. Why I had to do this? Hmmm? I copied all of the code from try to the end and simply modified the slider variable to texture2 instead of texture3 and now it works. Either a visual studio or unity bug I imagine.

Comment: never touch it again :D